# Import directory into pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to import a legacy project into pycharm for debugging.
The directory structure looks like:

top folder ---> folder one

top folder ---> folder two

The problem is that programs in the sub-folders use:

```
 import top 
 from top import module
```

Pycharm returns the error: "No module named top"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your top folder have an `__init__.py` file? If it does not, then it is not a module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First thing to make sure is to do what Games said, you need to make sure each folder that is representing a package is done by putting a `__init__.py` file which is a empty python file named exactly `__init__.py` that tells the interpreter that the folder is a python package.

Second thing to look for is that pycharm likes to complain about imported code if PyCharm does not know about that directory. Go into the Project Interpreter Configuration and go to *Paths* and add the path references that are not in the project or directly under the interpreter.

One other thing to add, is to set the source root of your project code by right clicking the folder that represents your root and clicking the 'Mark Directory as...' > 'Source Root'.

Comment: Is there a way to tell PyCharm to search in ALL of the modules/subfolders in the project?  We have a VERY tall directory structure, and it's really difficult to manually set all the folders as "Sources".

Comment: You dont have to set all directories as sources you just have to set the root. If you have multiple roots you may be organizing your project wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, but it's not caused by the lack of **init**.py file.
The reason is, there are two same name modules in the project, so PyCharm don't know how to import. The weird thing is PyCharm only report this error on the running time.

My Project Files:

```
source root1
   |-- moduleA
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- A.py

 source root2
   |-- moduleA
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- B.py
```

Actually, the source root1 is my code, and source root2 is my test code.

so the solution is to change the test module name.

```
 source root1
    |-- moduleA
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- A.py

 source root2
    |-- testmoduleA
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- B.py
```