# I have old commit from old assignment on git how do i get new fresh log for new commits?

Tags: git, pycharm

I am using Pycharm. It's showing old commits from a project in another folder. I created a new project and added VCS Git to it now its show logs from my old project and its commits and its logs. I want a fresh log and a cleared up commits.

Comment: Do i have to delete or move my old folder thats being read?

Comment: That didn't work...

Comment: So I need a complete new path to my directory...? 
Mine was like this and it was stacking: Assignments>[one][two]

Answer (score 1):

It is best to initialize a new Git repo locally in command-line first:

```
cd /path/to/new/folder
git init .
# Add some project files, including at least one with `__init__.py`
```

(see "[Import directory into pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338397/6309)")

Then import that folder into PyCharm.